# What is Mola Ram looking at in this shot?

Tags: indiana-jones, indiana-jones-and-temple-of-doom

In "Indiana Jones and the Temple of Doom", what is Mola Ram looking at in this shot below? Is he looking at the Maharajah or is he looking at Willie, Short Round and Indy?

I just wonder because I have a feeling he might have been looking at Indy, Willie and Short Round since a while later some Thuggee Guards jump out and capture them as if they were hiding so he might of known they were up where they were watching the Sacrifice.

[image: Mola Ram looking at something with a crazy look]

Comment: I always thought it was just meant to be a crazy stare, adding to the insanity of the character.  That Trilogy (later, Quadrilogy) was pretty direct in what was going on at all times, if he was looking up towards Indy I'd think they'd have shown a cut to Indy's POV and shown Mola Ram staring at him.

Comment: If Moola Ram is looking downward he can't be looking upward at Indy.  So it depends on his posture. Possibly Moola Ram knows that Indy is about to be captured, or maybe he is just thinking about all the evil deeds he has done and plans to do.

Comment: That's a face which shows victory, and satisfaction towards achieving their goal(s)